# How to append always a value to when a jquery post happens?

Tags: jquery

I have a huge application where jquery post is used extensively. My Requirement is I need post a value every time a post call happens on to the server. But I need to change all the places where ever post data is written. Instead is there any way to append my value for the data which is being posted?

Thanks in advance.
Kiran

Comment: Nobody can stop you from changing the method in the JQuery sources and appending your custom code - but I definitely wouldn't go that way.

Answer (score 0):

try with [$.ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/):

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    data: {
        "abc": new Date()  //this will be set in every ajax request
    }
});
```

and then use `$.ajax()`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {.. your other data here },
    url: "some url",
    success: function( respo ) {
       ...
    }
});
```

you will get `abc` as added in `ajaxSetup` in your POST data, along with your other data

Comment: as per your suggestion I tried adding this like below

 $(document).ready(function() {
          
                     
            $.ajaxSetup({
                type: "POST",
                data:{ "abc" : new Date()}

            });
             
        });

but this seems to not working..please suggest

Comment: @user2702412 see my added answer